# Laravel Glide not finding images at urls with extension

Tags: laravel, image-manipulation, php-glide

I am using Glide, and followed this video https://vimeo.com/118089742 which basically is a walk-through
for the instructions on the official site http://glide.thephpleague.com/

Here is my service provider:

```
$this->app->singleton('League\Glide\Server', function ($app) {

        return \League\Glide\ServerFactory::create([
                'source' => public_path(),
                'cache' => public_path(),
                'source_path_prefix' => 'images/uploads',
                'cache_path_prefix' => 'images/cache',
                'base_url' => '/img/',
        ]);
    });
```

And here is my current route:

```
Route::get('img/{path}', function (League\Glide\Server $server, Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $server->outputImage($request);
});
```

But I am running into problems. When I go to url.com/img/test.png?h=100, it does not work. When looking at chrome
dev tools on the page, I get a 404 for the image (however, the original image DOES appear).

I have found that if I switch my route to the following, and only go to url.com/img/test?h=100 (without the extension),
then I get the Glided image that I want:

```
 Route::get('img/{path}', function (League\Glide\Server $server,  Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $server->outputImage($request->path() . '.png', $request->all());
});
```

However, if I remove the concatenation of the extension and go with simply:

```
Route::get('img/{path}', function (League\Glide\Server $server,  Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $server->outputImage($request->path(), $request->all());
});
```

Then route back to url.com/img/test.png?h=100, it fails again.

Do you see anything wrong with what I'm doing, or is there an explanation for why I can't go directly to the image 
path (with the extension)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and tried many things. All url's starting with /img/ are Glide generated images. All in /assets/ are static files.
I've given up and changed

`location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$`

to

`location ~* ^/assets/.*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$`.

Hopefully someone has a good solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

It was all a caching problem. Don't cache your images via htaccess or nginx before using Glide.

Comment: Running into the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911127/laravel-glide-404-accessing-images-nginx-cache-issue Only works when I disable expiry headers. Any tips on how I can enable again?