# Laravel Glide - 404 Accessing Images: NGINX Cache Issue

Tags: laravel, caching, nginx, laravel-5.1

Within my Laravel 5.1 app, I'm using https://github.com/thephpleague/glide to resize and serve images via a `.cache` directory once resized. I am running into the exact same issue as [Laravel Glide not finding images at urls with extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332539/laravel-glide-not-finding-images-at-urls-with-extension)

Have had to disable caching in NGINX:

```
# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
  expires -1;
  access_log logs/static.log;
}

# Feed
location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
  expires 1h;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# WebFonts
# If you are NOT using cross-domain-fonts.conf, uncomment the following directive
location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
 expires 1M;
 access_log off;
 add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

After disabling these rules I can access the images again. Any tips? I can still "see" the images when enabling this, but my server cannot read them. A little lost on what could be going on here. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|' out of your matches, restart nginx, clear browser cache. Glide will sort the caching out for your images.